# What is difference between begin() and data()

Tags: c++, vector, stl

`begin()` and `data()` both returns iterator pointing to the first element. But, the definition of `data()` says it Returns a direct pointer to the memory array used internally by the vector to store its owned elements. I can also use them to access any element. So, how both of them are different? consider the following example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(5);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i ++) v.push_back(i);
    
    auto it = v.begin();
    auto pos = v.data();

    std::cout << "First element : " << *it << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First element : " << *pos << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Third element : " << it[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Third element : " << pos[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You are mistaken. Only one of these methods returns an iterator. The other one does not.

Comment: [`std::vector<T>::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) versus [`std::vector<T>::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik from a certain point of view, the OP is not actually wrong. A pointer is a valid iterator. Iterators are designed to mimic pointers. So, in that sense, `begin()` and `data()` both return iterators to the first element, just different types of iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All container types have an `iterator`, but only some container types are contiguous and support `data()`. For example,

```cpp
vector<int> v;
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
v.data(); // ok

list<int> l;
copy(l.begin(), l.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
l.data(); // no
```

It is true that the `int*` from `int* vector<int>::data()` satisfies `iterator_traits<int*>::iterator_category == random_access_iterator_tag`, and that `vector<int>::iterator` can be implemented as an `int*`. However, the standard does not mandate that, and it would be legal to implement `vector<int>::iterator` with something like

```cpp
class vector<T> {
    class iterator {
        vector<T>* v;
        vector<T>::size_type pos;
    };
};
```

Hence, without `data()`, you had to resort to tricks like `&v[0]` or `&*v.front()` to get access to the underlying contiguous memory backing a `vector`. This was the state of things before C++11 introduced `data()`.

Answer (score 4):

```cpp
std::vector::begin()
```

[v.begin()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) returns an **iterator** referring to the first element in the vector.

```cpp
std::vector::data()
```

[v.data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) returns a **pointer** to the first element in the array used internally by the vector.